# Removing DIV element on word press site

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to remove a DIV element that is part of a plugin on my WordPress site.

This is the element in question:

```css
<div class="blog pad-m pad-top-l powrMark text-center __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__">
<a class="powrMarkLink js-watermark watermark-create-free __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" href="https://www.powr.io?utm_source=watermark&amp;utm_medium=plugin&amp;utm_campaign=watermark_2019&amp;utm_content=social-feed" target="_blank">
<img class="powrMark__logo-block" src="https://www.powrcdn.com/powrmark/powr-full-logo%20blue.png">
<span class="powrMark__text">
Create your own <u>Social Feed</u> - for free!
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

So far I have tried this, but to no avail.

```css
.blog.pad-m.pad-top-l.powrMark.text-center.__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__
{
display:none;
}
```

I've also tried to add an Important tag, but still nothing.

```css
.blog.pad-m.pad-top-l.powrMark.text-center.__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__
{
display:none!important;
}
```

When I hide the element in chrome this is what comes up in the inspector:

```css
.__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__, .__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__ *, .__web-inspector-hidebefore-shortcut__::before, .__web-inspector-hideafter-shortcut__::after {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: just write .powrMark  for css. You don't need to write all class names

Answer (score 1):

```css
div.blog.pad-m.pad-top-l.powrMark.text-center.__web-inspector-hide-shortcut__ .powrMarkLink
{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog pad-m pad-top-l powrMark text-center __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__">
<a class="powrMarkLink js-watermark watermark-create-free __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" href="https://www.powr.io?utm_source=watermark&amp;utm_medium=plugin&amp;utm_campaign=watermark_2019&amp;utm_content=social-feed" target="_blank">
<img class="powrMark__logo-block" src="https://www.powrcdn.com/powrmark/powr-full-logo%20blue.png">
<span class="powrMark__text">
Create your own <u>Social Feed</u> - for free!
</span>
</a>
</div>
```